# Microsoft Excel Custom Label Overlay on Line Graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

I have 2 tables identical.

One records the progression of projects as a percentage over dates until completion.

The other is a replica table but records the daily status of the projects on the corresponding dates from the first table.

Plotting the first set of data is easy:

```
        08/07/2014  09/07/2014  10/07/2014  11/07/2014  12/07/2014
Project 1   10  20  25  30  35
Project 2   5   5   10  10  15
Project 3   0   0   0   0   0
Project 4   0   0   10  20  50
Project 5   0   0   0   0   0
```

This can be used to create a graph.

The markers (data labels) I want to correspond with data existing in the following table

```
        08/07/2014  09/07/2014  10/07/2014  11/07/2014  12/07/2014
Project 1   BLOCKED BLOCKED BLOCKED BLOCKED BLOCKED
Project 2   SCHEDULED   SCHEDULED   SCHEDULED   WIP BLOCKED
Project 3   SCHEDULED   SCHEDULED   SCHEDULED   WIP BLOCKED
Project 4   SCHEDULED   BLOCKED SCHEDULED   WIP BLOCKED
Project 5   SCHEDULED   SCHEDULED   SCHEDULED   WIP BLOCKED
```

There is nowhere on the internet that seems to have the same issue. I am using Excel 2010.

Can anyone help me resolve this problem!

Comment: What type of chart are you trying to create?

Comment: a line graph with markers

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to label the markers with the words "Blocked" etc the easiest way is to use the free add in xychartlabeler found [here](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm).

If you want all the to use a certain marker shape for the different labels you would need to build them as seperate series for each label.  Use line graphs without markers for the first table and split the second table into 3 seperate tables using something like '`=if(B5="Blocked",B2,na())`

Then you plot each of this split tables as a series using a different marker style.